# Date Field is different for US Users in Alfresco Content Application

Tags: angular, alfresco, alfresco-share

In Alfresco content application, I am showing "Added On" Field in GRID as below screenshot, My problem is this Added On Date is showing as local time for US Users but I need to show them also SGT Time. could anyone help me to resolve this issue.

SGT Time:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeQDs.png)

for US Users:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6BQL.png)

In Alfresco share we are saving like :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yybz2.png)

Alfresco Content app Code:

```
<data-column title="Added On" [key]="docCreatedKey" type="date"></data-column>
```

Alfresco Link : https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/content-services/components/document-list.component/